# Global color of trooper or starfighter class

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

When you select a trooper or starfighter class, it has a global level, which is the sum of the Star Cards for this class (a common card gives 1 point, an uncommon 2 points, a rare 3 points and an epic 4 points).

However, I don't get the global color. For exemple, in my Heavy class, I do have 6 cards (2 common, 3 uncommon, 1 rare). The three uncommon (green) are equipped. My Heavy trooper is level 11 (2 + 6 + 3) with grey color.

I have, for the Interceptor class, 3 cards (1 common, 2 uncommon). My level is 5 with green color.

I then thought you have to have the majority of your cards of a given color to have the global level of this color.

But I have for the Bomber class, 4 cards (2 common, 2 uncommon). Global level is a green 6, where I would have thought it would be grey.

So if anyone know how this color is selected and if it is of any use in-game...

Comment: I think you have to look at them separately. For trooper classes 15 will give you the green color, 30 will give you a blue color and I think there will probably a purple at 45. For starfighter classes because there are less cards in total I think it will be green 5

Comment: @Lyrion Looks like you're right. Troopers and starfighters/heroes/specialists are handled differently. Looks like only the global level is used with 15/30/45(?) is used for troopers and 5/15/? for the others. You can post an answer with this that we can complete afterwards for the higher tiers.

Answer (score 2):

The color is just for show and has no point. It shows the card level, the card level for troops is higher because they have more star cards. Trooper classes get a green color at 15 and blue at 30.

For the startfighters, reinforcements and heroes the color coding is 5 for green ,15 for blue and 25 for purple.

I haven't gotten a class to the purple color so I am not sure at what levels those show.

Comment: I've seen a blue trooper level 35, so not before 40 at least it seems...